# rxjs with optional api call

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is my code. i have to validate userno & email while submit form.
But userno exist is conditional based on user Type and emailvalidation common for all users..

THis is code

```
save()
{
    numexist:false;emailexist:false;
    
    if(type=="Manual")
    {      
           this.userService.IsUserNoExist(no).subscribe({
              next: (result: any)  => {            
                numexist=result;
              },
              error: (error:any) => {
                this.close();
              }
            });  
      }  //if
    
    //Email Check common for all user type  
    this.userService.IsEmailExist(email).subscribe({
              next: (result: any)  => {            
                emailexist=result;
              },
              error: (error:any) => {
                this.close();
              }
            });  
            
 if(numexist==false && emailexist==false)
    {  // Here comes before result come from email exist
               //Save
            }
            else
            {
              //nothify
            }               
 }
```

I Have written multiple subsribe method..but i have to check both condition process save ..please let me know which operator i have to join forkjoin not for optional case please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (exact syntax not tested):

```
userNoExists$ =  iif(()=> type==="Manual",
                     this.userService.IsUserNoExist(no).pipe(
                        tap((result: any)  => numexist=result),
                        catchError((error:any) => this.close())
                     ),
                     of(null)
              );
```

If the type is "manual", call the service, process the result, and emit the value. Otherwise, emit null (or this could emit false).

For more information on `iif` see: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif

Then

```
  emailExists$ = this.userService.IsEmailExist(email).pipe(
                  tap((result: any)  => emailexist=result),
                  catchError((error:any) => this.close())
               );
```

And

```
  save() {
     combineLatest([
         this.userNoExists$,
         this.emailExists$
     ]).pipe(
        map([numexist, emailexist]) => {
            if(numexist==false && emailexist==false)
            {  // Save 
            }
            else
            {
               //nothify
            }
        })
     ).subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you..userNoExists$ is behaviour subject or some thing else?

Comment: It's the observable returned from the iif function.

Comment: Am getting error pipe map array inside combinelatest method.....removed pipe map  and condition checked inside subscribe method...now this is working...thanks a lot